# magento 1.7.0.2 Update to 1.9.1.0 - content in the backend is missing

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0

magento 1.7.0.2 Update **to 1.9.1.0** - **content (products/cms) in the backend is missing**.

The navigation is displayed completely. The configuration is also there.

In front are all present. There is a copy on the localhost and Xampp

First = New version installed:
Second = I used this guide: http://www.fol9000.de/magento/magento-update-1-7-0-2-nach-1-8-0-0/

I'm still Magento beginners :)

could this been the problem (single shop)???[image: single shop]

[image: products]

[image: categories]

Comment: check error logs, all of them, browser console, etc

Comment: Are you saying you can't see any products or cms data in your Admin?

Comment: Yes i can't see products and cms data

Comment: What does that exception message say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if all files are copied. Had this problem a few times when downloading over ssh.
Unfortunately I had to upload them with ftp in those cases.

But first, clear all caches, log out an re-login to make sure the problem is not cache or acl related.

Comment: Now it works fine - "copied all files again" - Many thanks